# What should I do when pipenv lock command is not working?

Tags: python, django, heroku, pipenv

I'm trying to do a command `pipenv lock` 'cause heroku said my Pipfile.lock is out of date, and I'm trying to upload my django project at heroku. But I constantly got the error like below.

```
PS C:\Users\josep\Documents\nomad academy\Airbnb-Clone> pipenv lock --pre --clear
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
 Locking...Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Locking Failed!
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\josep\.virtualenvs\airbnb-clone-grekw6gp\lib\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\josep\.virtualenvs\airbnb-clone-grekw6gp\lib\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 702, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\josep\.virtualenvs\airbnb-clone-grekw6gp\lib\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 684, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\josep\.virtualenvs\Airbnb-Clone-GrEkW6GP\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 1395, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\josep\.virtualenvs\Airbnb-Clone-GrEkW6GP\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\josep\.virtualenvs\Airbnb-Clone-GrEkW6GP\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 833, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pathspec<1,==0.5.9,>=0.6 (from black==20.8b1->-r C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenvnt4vjek5requirements\pipenv-0sidr1ev-constraints.txt (line 4))  
Tried: 0.2.2, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.5, 0.5.6, 0.5.7, 0.5.8, 0.5.9, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.1
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  pathspec<1,>=0.6 (from black==20.8b1->-r C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenvnt4vjek5requirements\pipenv-0sidr1ev-constraints.txt (line 4))
  pathspec==0.5.9 (from awsebcli==3.19.2->-r C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenvnt4vjek5requirements\pipenv-0sidr1ev-constraints.txt (line 3))
```

I searched about that a bit, and I tried quite many like `pipenv lock`,`pipenv lock --clear`,etc. But none of them working for me. And according to error, it seems that I'm having this error because of the version issue, but I've got no idea what pipenv want me to do to fix this. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  pathspec<1,>=0.6 from black==20.8b1
  pathspec==0.5.9 from awsebcli==3.19.2

Which clearly points that these 2 versions of packages require different versions of pathspec

Comment: Change the version of the packages that require `pathspec` (`black` and `awsebcli`) or try with [poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry#dependency-resolution).

Comment: Thanks for your helps! I've tried the version change, but it still doesn't worked for me. I solved that problem by uninstalling awsebcli, 'cause I'm not using amazon's elastic beanstalk now. But still thanks for your comments!